# Git failure in uploading using "git push origin master"

Tags: git, heroku

Many people are facing problem in using

```
git push heroku master
```

The see an error similar to one stated below:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to correct the above error is to do either of the following options:

1. Logout and login again to your heroku account.
2. use `ssh-add` and then try `git push heroku master` again
3. Remove your ssh keys using `heroku keys:clear` and then login again, this would add back your keys and hopefully make `git push origin master` work.

One of the above options should make it work.